# How do we obtain the posterior of a beta binomial mixture of continuous and a discrete density?

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, posterior, mixture-distribution

In section 3.6 of Jim Albert's 2009 book "Bayesian Computation with R" he describes a test of whether a coin is fair using a mixture of priors. The coin tossing follows a binomial distribution so the likelihood is $\binom{n}{y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}$. The prior is given as mixture:
$$g(p) = 0.5\  I(p=0.5) + 0.5\ I(p \ne 0.5) \texttt{beta}(p, a, a)$$
The second term is a beta distribution and a previous section has covered mixtures with two such. But this mixture has on the left a function which is .5 when p=.5 and zero everywhere else.

To apply Bayes rule to get the posterior $g(p|y)$ I multiply the likelihood by the prior for the numerator:

$$
\binom{n}{y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y} \times  \bigl( 0.5\  I(p=0.5) + 0.5\ I(p \ne 0.5) \ \texttt{beta}(p, a, a)\bigr) \tag{1}
$$

For the denominator I must "integrate out" the parameter $p$ from (1) then the posterior is just numerator/denominator. My difficulty is that I cannot do this - I don't understand how to handle the indicator functions to obtain the posterior density.

I attach an image of how Albert continues the discussion (note that there is no explanation of $f(y|p)$ which is perhaps the $p(y|p)$, the binomial probability of $y$ given $p$?).

[image: Albert Text]

Comment: To help you just discriminate the prior mixture components and calculate the posterior distribution independently of each other. Plain speaking the posterior is gonna be just the sum of those two posteriors.